# Android Emulator automatically scrolls down

Tags: android, android-listview, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I try to scroll through a `scrollView` or `listView` the Android Emulator automatically scrolls down to the very end of the view. It's impossible to scroll up again, because it just scrolls down again immediately. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Hi firozSujan, if the answer below solved your problem please accept it as the answer. This will help other people in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just faced the same problem.  In my case it appeared to be an issue with using the Intel Atom x86 process settings in my AVD.  I also had installed the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM).

I noticed when launching the AVD that I was getting some errors and warnings regarding HAXM.  After changing my AVD settings to use ARM instead of Intel, the scrolling issues seemed to stop.

If you are using have your AVD setup to use the Intel Atom processor, I would recommend trying the ARM setting and see if you still see the problem.

Comment: Thanks you saved my day